# Getting column names with BCP queryout

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I need to BCP a table into a tab-delimited file, but I need the column names in the first record of the table.  Question 1:  Am I right that BCP does not have a switch for this?  Question 2:  If not, why?

I tried to do the following:

```
BCP "declare @colnames varchar(max); select @colnames=coalesce (@colnames+char(9), '') 
+ Column_Name from db.information_Schema.columns where table_name='table1' order by 
ordinal_position; select @colnames" queryout Table1_Columns.tsv -S?? -U?? -P?? -f** -e**
```

The format file looks like this:

```
9.0
1
1 SQLCHAR 0 100 "\r\n" 1 Column_Names SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

This gets me a file of the column names, then a second BCP command gets me a file of data, and I just DOS-copy the two together.  Question 3:  Am I clever or what?  Question 4:  Why doesn't it work?  I get the error:

```
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Host-file columns may be skipped only when 
copying into the Server
```

Answer (score 8):

bcp does not support exporting the column headers with the data, however there are some workarounds like exporting the headers in a separate file, then merging both the headers and data files as the following:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "select 'SETTINGS_ID','GROUP_NAME'" queryout d:\header.csv  -c  -T -t,'

exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "select SETTINGS_ID,GROUP_NAME from [DB]..[TABLE]" queryout "d:\columns.csv" -c -t, -T '

exec master..xp_cmdshell 'copy /b "d:\header.csv"+"d:\columns.csv" "d:/result.csv"'
```

You may also delete the unused files:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'del "d:\header.csv"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'del "d:\columns.csv"'
```

Or maybe you can combine all the data in a view (adding headers) and export it

Comment: the first line does not work for me: `'SETTINGS_ID' is not a recognized option`. Any clue ?

Comment: You have to replace it with your own column headers.

Comment: how can you use copy command with location as a parameter? ex: `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'copy /b "' + @OutputLocationHeader +'" + "'+ @OutputLocationData + '" "' + @OutputLocation +'"'` it is giving me an error for the first `+` sign