# Exporting SQL result to excel file with headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am running a query on SQL Server to get result. The result contains four header columns (ext type, count, size, percentage).

I am using a command to get the SQL result into an Excel sheet. But I am not able to get headers in the Excel sheet.

```
bcp "dbo.DumpFileStats" queryout DSFFileStats.csv -d DB_Name -U sa -P XXXXX -c -t"\",\"" -r"\"\n\"" -T
```

Is there something I am missing?

-Kalyan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226847/getting-column-names-with-bcp-queryout

Answer (score 0):

can't you do this with a simple SQL query?  IE

```
SELECT id,this,that
FROM table
INTO OUTFILE '/dir/file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks all. Working now.