# SQL BCP with column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, bcp

I am trying to export my stored procedure to a .csv file using BCP. It does give me a output file in .CSV but it does not print column name.
Below is the script. Please look at and let me know what i am missing

```
    DECLARE @command VARCHAR(4000)
    declare @fulldate varchar(30) = convert(varchar,GETDATE(),112)
    declare @year varchar(30) = left(@fulldate,4)
    declare @day  varchar(30) = right(@fulldate,2)
    declare @month varchar(30) = left(right(@fulldate,4),2)
    DECLARE @FileDirectory VARCHAR(1000) = 'c:\'
    DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(255)= 'TestingDOC' + @month + '.' + @day + '.'      + @year  + '.txt'
    declare @attach varchar(1255) = @fileDirectory + @fileName

    SET @command = 'bcp "select * from ngprod.dbo.TEMP_PAS"'
        + ' queryout "' + @FileDirectory + @FileName + '"'
        + ' -c -t, -T -S'+ @@servername
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command
```

Comment: While easy to write in this case, SQL is not really the best tool for ETL, especially as things start getting complicated.  I would suggest moving to an ETL tool.

Comment: A simple Powershell script could do the job too.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example of how to use power shell script in stored procedure to output a file with header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [export table to file with column headers (column names) using the bcp utility and SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355876/export-table-to-file-with-column-headers-column-names-using-the-bcp-utility-an)

Comment: Also, this one: [Getting column names with BCP queryout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24733192/243373)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trail and error below is the answer on how to add column

First create a header.txt file (inside the header file add all of you header)
for example if the header file need firstname, lastname etc

second paste the below query in your stored procedure

```
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(4000)

DECLARE @FileDirectory VARCHAR(1000) = 'c:\test\'

DECLARE @HeaderFile varchar(255) = 'Headers.txt'

DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(255)

SET @FileName = 'TestFile_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)

SET @command = 'bcp "select * from TESTDB.dbo.TEST_Table"'

       + ' queryout "' + @FileDirectory + @FileName + '.txt"'

       + ' -c -q -t, -T  -S'+@@servername

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command

SET @command =  'copy "' + @FileDirectory + @HeaderFile + '"+"' + @FileDirectory + @FileName + '.txt"' +  ' "' + @FileDirectory + @filename + '.csv"'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command

SET @command = 'del "' + @FileDirectory + @FileName + '.txt"'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is do a union all with the column names when you are using queryout.

so an example is provided below.

```
select 'col1','col2',col3','col4' ... etc
union all
select col1,col2,col3,col4 ... etc from yourtable
```